# Sorting 32 bit ints is as fast as sorting 64 bit ints

Tags: c++, caching, memory, int

Here are things I believe are facts:

- Quick sort should be fairly cache friendly.
- A cache line of 64 bytes can contain 16 32-bit ints, or 8 64-bit ints.

Hypothesis:

- Sorting a vector of 32-bit integers should be faster than sorting a
  vector of 64-bit integers.

But when I run the code below I get the result:

```
i16 = 7.5168 
i32 = 7.3762 
i64 = 7.5758
```

Why am I not getting the results I want?

C++:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>


int main() {
  const int vlength = 100'000'000;
  const int maxI = 50'000;

  std::vector<int16_t> v16;
  for (int i = 0; i < vlength; ++i) {
    v16.push_back(int16_t(i%maxI));
  }
  std::random_shuffle(std::begin(v16), std::end(v16));
  std::vector<int32_t> v32;
  std::vector<int64_t> v64;
  for (int i = 0; i < vlength; ++i) {
    v32.push_back(int32_t(v16[i]));
    v64.push_back(int64_t(v16[i]));
  }

  auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::sort(std::begin(v16), std::end(v16));
  auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std :: cout << "i16 = " << (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - t1)).count() << std :: endl;

  t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::sort(std::begin(v32), std::end(v32));
  t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std :: cout << "i32 = " << (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - t1)).count() << std :: endl;

  t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::sort(std::begin(v64), std::end(v64));
  t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std :: cout << "i64 = " << (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - t1)).count() << std :: endl;

}
```

**EDIT:** 
In order to avoid the question of how cache friendly sort is, I've also tried the following code:

```
template <typename T>
inline void function_speed(T& vec) {
  for (auto& i : vec) {
    ++i;
  }
}

int main() {
  const int nIter = 1000;

  std::vector<int16_t> v16(1000000);
  std::vector<int32_t> v32(1000000);
  std::vector<int64_t> v64(1000000);



  auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for (int i = 0; i < nIter; ++i) {
    function_speed(v16);
  }
  auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std :: cout << "i16 = " << (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - t1)).count()/double(nIter) << std :: endl;

  t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for (int i = 0; i < nIter; ++i) {
    function_speed(v32);
  }
  t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std :: cout << "i32 = " << (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - t1)).count()/double(nIter) << std :: endl;

  t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for (int i = 0; i < nIter; ++i) {
    function_speed(v64);
  }
  t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std :: cout << "i64 = " << (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - t1)).count()/double(nIter) << std :: endl;

}
```

Typical result:

```
i16 = 0.00618648
i32 = 0.00617911
i64 = 0.00606275
```

I know that proper benchmarking is a science of itself, perhaps I am doing to wrong.

**EDIT2:**
By avoiding overflowing I am now starting to get more interesting results:

```
template <typename T>
inline void function_speed(T& vec) {
  for (auto& i : vec) {
    ++i;
    i %= 1000;
  }
}
```

Gives results such as:

```
i16 = 0.0143789
i32 = 0.00958941
i64 = 0.019691
```

If I instead do:

```
template <typename T>
inline void function_speed(T& vec) {
  for (auto& i : vec) {
    i = (i+1)%1000;
  }
}
```

I get:

```
i16 = 0.00939448
i32 = 0.00913768
i64 = 0.019615
```

Comment: 7.5, is that seconds? or millis?

Comment: Which difference (factor) did you expect ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Seconds.

Comment: @Jarod42: I'm not sure how big of a difference I expected, but something noticeable, at least.

Comment: By the way, you have overflows when you try to store numbers `>= 32768` in 16-bit signed int. But that shouldn't change any of the benchmarks since the overflowed values are copied as-is to the other vectors.

Comment: A counting sort will beat the other sorts on the `int16_t` case, actually.

Comment: @NicuStiurca: Actually, the overflow may tip off modern optimizers that the values don't need to be copied at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mistaken assumption; all O(N log N) sorting algorithms *have* to be cache-unfriendly for the vast majority of the N! possible inputs.

Furtehrmore, I think an optimizing compiler can remove the sorts outright, and an unoptimized build will of course be pointless to benchmark.

Comment: I always thought a merge sort would be cache friendly, as long as you had at least a 3-way cache.

Comment: @MarkRansom: At the end it is, when merging large sequences. And the early stuff isn't too bad either, when operating on a single cache line (although you'd probably not use merge sort down to the last 2 elements; instead you'd use dedicated sorters for the cache-line level). The middle part looks rather bad, though, and I think you'll still have  O(N log N) cache misses. The prefetcher probably helps.

Comment: I don't buy the cache unfriendlyness as a reason for the lack of performance difference. Cache unfriendlyness guarantees that you have to make O(n log n) memory accesses for all three int sizes. _But you are still reading 4x as many bytes in the int64 case vs the int16 case._ So if this is memory bound algorithm, then there should be a 4x speed difference in benchmark.

Comment: Actually, I just thought about it for 3 more seconds and realized that in the int16 case, even though each memory fetch grabs 2 bytes of useful data per comparison, the architecture still pulls in the surrounding 62 bytes, so each memory fetch is 64 bytes regardless of number of bits in the int.

Comment: @NicuStiurca: Correct, and it's rather critical how well a sorting algorithm uses those nearby values. The problem is that on average, nearby input values end half an array away in the output. There's only so many 12 byte moves you need to make, and here you need many moves over >100MB distance.